# Remove range of numeric from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scripting, logic

I have an array of [2016,2017,2018,2019]

I have a range fromValue 2017 toValue 2017

Hence resulting array should be [2017]  because of i need to remove whatever out of range between fromValue and toValue.

I have written code below which is only removing 2016 and 2018 but not 2019.

Whats wrong i am doing , is there any beter way to do this?

```
gNodeIDs.forEach(function (item) {              
    alert("Before if" + item);
    if (item >= fromValue) {
        if (item <= toValue) {                        
        }
        else
        {
            alert("removing" + item);
            var index = test.indexOf(item);
            if (index >= 0) {
                test.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("removing" + item);
        var index = test.indexOf(item);
        if (index >= 0) {
            test.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: how?  to use filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve this:

```
var result = gNodeIDs.filter(function(item) { return item >= fromValue && item <= toValue });
```

`result` array with contain all matching items

Comment: Probably not a problem, but worth mentioning this was added in JavaScript 1.6. However, there is a polyfill if you're worried about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control

Comment: @SmartestVEGA glad it helped, please, do not forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using Array.prototype.filter is the correct answer, but it's worth noting you are not using the `forEach` function correctly. According to [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control)

> The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first invocation of callback. Elements that are appended to the array after the call to forEach() begins will not be visited by callback. If the values of existing elements of the array are changed, the value passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach() visits them; elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited. If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using shift()) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped - see example below.

If you wanted to use the `forEach` function then you should use 2 copies of the same array, the first for iterating and the second for removal.